# Recursive Property of Trees

Tags: graph-theory, recursion

Consider a tree $T$, and consider when we delete a vertex $v$ from $T$ that
the remaining connected components are consider branches at vertex $v$. I would
like to show that every tree has a vertex such that every branch at this node
contains at most half the vertices in a tree.

At first, this felt like a relatively intuitive result, although I have found
formally proving it to be somewhat difficult. Assume for the sake of
contradiction that for every vertex $v \in T$, there is a branch at $v$
that contains more than half of the vertices in the tree. Let us consider this
branch $B$. We realize that for each $v_B \in B$, there is a branch at
$v_B$ on $T$ that contains more than half of the vertices. However, I am
wondering if this contradicts the relationship that $v$ has to $B$ along with
the relationship that $v_B$ has to $B$. Any recommendations on how to move
forward with this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Start at an arbitrary vertex $v_0$. By assumption there is an adjacent vertex $v_1$ whose branch at $v_0$ contains more than half the vertices of the tree. Continue constructing a walk in the tree: given $v_k$, there is a vertex $v_{k+1}$ whose branch at $v_k$ contains more than half the vertices of the tree. Since the tree is acyclic, there must be some $k$ such that $v_{k+2}=v_k$: at $v_{k+1}$ the walk returns to $v_k$. Get a contradiction at this point.